# Rails Devise disable redirect for ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I want for one of the pages of the application has the ability to partially update some user settings.
Also the application already has a page to edit all settings.
I was faced with the fact that when I send a request for a partial update, the devise redirects me to the root, but I don`t want it.

Can I somehow disable redirection for the Ajax request, and leave for a page to edit all settings? Or at least turn it off for all pages at once?

Comment: Which route are you using for partially updating user settings?

Comment: I send PUT request to url "/users"

Comment: Please show what your form code. To edit an instance of a user you need to supply the id of the user as e.g. /users/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see closely in [devise/registrations_controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d2ea28b3dbbf3e11dc9e800179fb89c53d61fc71/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)'s `#update` method (which is used for `PUT /users`), you will find that it calls `#after_update_path_for` at `respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)` line.

So, if you just want to redirect to any other location, you can override the `#after_update_path_for`. Otherwise, you can override `#update` entirely (of course, you will need to write your own controller. There are many tutorials available on the Internet.), and prevent it from redirecting to any other location.